# How do I create a pointer to an array class member?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am trying to return the address of an array `@element` from my Hash Table using the find function. However, I am getting the compiler error:

```
QuadraticProbing.cpp:134:59: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
             return isActive( currentPos ) ? wordElement : ITEM_NOT_FOUND;
```

Basically, I just want to return a pointer to `@element`. So I tried creating a pointer `wordElement` to `@element` and tried returning `wordElement`. But that didn't work. Here is a snippet of my code, I can't figure out how to get a pointer to `@element` in HashEntry.

```
//Main
int main()
{
    QuadraticHashTable<char*> table(100);
    table.insert("HELLO WORLD");
    if (table.find(document[i]) == NULL))
        cout << "OH NO!";
}

//Class that has element that I want to return in find.
template <class HashedObj>
class QuadraticHashTable
{
  public:
    QuadraticHashTable()

    const HashedObj & find( const HashedObj & x ) const;

    enum EntryType { ACTIVE, EMPTY, DELETED };
  private:
    struct HashEntry
    {
        char element[20];
        EntryType info;


        HashEntry( const HashedObj & e = HashedObj( ), EntryType i = EMPTY )
          : info( i ) 
          {
            if (e != NULL)
                strcpy(element, e);
          }
    };
        vector<HashEntry> array;

//Find Function
    template <class HashedObj>
    const HashedObj & QuadraticHashTable<HashedObj>::find( const HashedObj & x ) const
    {
        int currentPos = findPos( x );
        const char * wordElement = array[currentPos].element;
        return isActive( currentPos ) ? wordElement : ITEM_NOT_FOUND;
    }
```

Comment: We have no idea what ITEM_NOT_FOUND is, but the design is not viable regardless. `array[currentPos].element` is a `char` array. The function tries to return a `HashedObj &`. This cannot work. And why are you designing in a special "not-a-value" value? Do you know what [the billion dollar mistake](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/3186) is?

Answer (score 2):

```
QuadraticHashTable<char*> table(100);
table.insert("HELLO WORLD");
```

A `HashedObject` is a `char*`

You pass `"HELLO WORLD"` to `insert`, which expects a `const HashedObject&`.

The `const` there applies at the top level, so it is a `char* const&` not a `const char*&` (which would be a different error).

Given that your entries are basically `char[20]` and how you wrote the entry, this code only works if `HashedObject`s are raw C strings.  The template parameter is pointless as written.  So there is that.

But `char const*` as the template parameter is the other way to make your code compile.  But really, a template that works with exactly one type is pretty pointless.